# Find distribution of a random variable sequence

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X_n$ be the sequence of random variables which have their values from $(0, n]$ for $n > 0$. The cumulative distributive function of $X_n$ is $F_{X_n}(x) = 1 - (1 - x/n)^n$ for $0 < x \leq n$. Find a distribution of $X = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}X_n$.

We defined distribution of $X$ (briefly said) as $\mu_X(B) = P(X \in B)$ for every borrel set $B$. We defined CDF as $F_X(x) = P(X \leq x)$, $x \in R$.

It is possible that the problem should ask for CDF.

Basically, I don't have any idea what to do. The only thing I thought of was to count a limit of $F_{X_n}$'s, but I don't have any Theorem suggesting it's the right path.

Comment: Here's a hint:  what is $$\lim_{n \to \infty} 1 - (1-x/n)^n?$$  What does this suggest about the distribution of $X$?

Comment: Well, it's $1 - e^{-x}$, but I don't know what does it suggest. My intuition is really bad in this topic.

Comment: What is the distribution of a random variable whose CDF is $F_X(x) = 1-e^{-x}$ for $x \in (0, \infty)$?  If you don't recognize it, differentiate it to get the density $$f_X(x) = e^{-x}, \quad x > 0.$$  What kind of distribution is this?

Comment: I guess exponential distribution (but what's $\mu_X(B)$ then?), but even if it is true, I don't see why. I don't know any theorem supporting it.

Comment: I will ask this way: how do I know that if CDFs converge to some function $F$, then $X_n$'s converge to $X$ and $F$ is CDF of $X$?

Comment: If the textbook suggested the notation $X=\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n$ for this problem, then I would say that it is a really dangerous choice. This is because convergence in distribution has almost nothing to do with convergence of $X_n$'s as functions, whereas the notation $\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n$ suggests something about limit of $X_n$'s as functions (such as a.s.- convergence, $L^p$-convergence, etc). As an extreme case, convergence in distribution can be discussed for a sequence of random variables $(X_n)_{n\geq1}$ where $X_n$'s for different $n$'s live on different probability spaces!

Answer (score 1):

You have that $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} 1-(1-\dfrac{x}{n})^{n}=1-e^{-x} , \forall x > 0$ . This is the distribution function called exponential. This is the distribution function of X. Due to the definition of Convergence in Distribution: $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} F_{X_{n}}(t) =F_{X} (t), \forall t$ a continuous value for X.